# How to use AspectJ to change Log4j output file name dynamically

Tags: logging, log4j, aspectj

I have multiple versions of the same application deployed in one Tomcat. Each of them has the same Log4j config file. So when all those applications write logs they end up in the same directory.

I am wondering if there is a way to dynamically update the logs' respective locations based on the version number of the application deployed.

Comment: If you know the version number why do you need AOP to do this?

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Because I have no Tomcat experience, I am just using an arbitrary JAR file (Apache Commons Compress 1.4.1) to [read manifest data](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do;jsessionid=8998920430CAF122E849421694189F6E?Id=238) from. You can easily adjust the sample code to fit your needs.

Assume you have an application like this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aop.java;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream;
import org.apache.log4j.*;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ZipArchiveInputStream.class);
        logger.addAppender(new ConsoleAppender(new SimpleLayout()));
        logger.addAppender(new FileAppender(new SimpleLayout(), "my.log"));
        logger.info("Logger: " + logger.getName());
        logger.info("Appenders:");
        for (Enumeration<Appender> appenders = logger.getAllAppenders(); appenders.hasMoreElements();) {
            Appender appender = appenders.nextElement();
            if (appender instanceof FileAppender)
                logger.info("  " + appender + ": " + ((FileAppender) appender).getFile());
            else
                logger.info("  " + appender);
        }
    }
}
```

The output without AspectJ is as follows:

```
INFO - Logger: org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream
INFO - Appenders:
INFO -   org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender@32c41a
INFO -   org.apache.log4j.FileAppender@e89b94: my.log
```

No surprise here. Now let us assume we want to add a version number read from the manifest inside `ZipArchiveInputStream`'s parent JAR. In order to achieve this we can intercept constructor calls to Log4J `FileAppender` and just manipulate the 2nd paramater which happens to always be the file name. For simplicity's sake I am not intercepting the default constructor or any setters.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aop.aspectj;

import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream;
import org.apache.log4j.FileAppender;

public aspect LogFileChanger {
    pointcut fileAppenderCreation(String fileName) :
        call(public FileAppender.new(*, String, ..)) && args(*, fileName, ..);

    FileAppender around(String fileName) : fileAppenderCreation(fileName) {
        Class<?> clazz = ZipArchiveInputStream.class;
        Package pkg = clazz.getPackage();
        return proceed(fileName + "." + pkg.getSpecificationVersion());
    }
}
```

The output now changes as follows:

```
INFO - Logger: org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream
INFO - Appenders:
INFO -   org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender@12d03f9
INFO -   org.apache.log4j.FileAppender@5ffb18: my.log.1.4.1
```

Bingo! We have dynamically changed the log file name. `:-)`